# If $f \in H^1$ and $f=g$ a.e. or in $L^2$, is $g \in H^1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

If $f \in H^1(\Omega)$ and either 
$$f=g \quad\text{a.e.}$$
or 
$$f=g \quad\text{in $L^2(\Omega)$},$$
is $g \in H^1(\Omega)$?

I think since we identify functions that are equal almost everywhere that this result is true. However it still seems a bit strange to me.

Comment: Each $f \in L^{2}(\Omega)$ is an equivalence class $[f]$ of functions that are equal a.e., and your statement is that there exists a function in the equivalence class with a specific property. There needs to be a method for knowing if such a function exists in a given equivalence class, and knowing how to find it.

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence, are you saying the result I want is not true?

Comment: I was stating how to make sense of your statement. For example, if $[f]\in L^{2}(\Omega)$, is possible that there are two members of the equivalence class $[f]$ which are in $H^{2}(\Omega)$? Is there a way to test a representative element $f\in L^{2}(\Omega)$ to know if there is some element in $[f]$ which is $H^{1}(\Omega)$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this statement ist true since $H^1(\Omega)$ is a subspace of $L^2(\Omega)$. Moreover, both conditions, i.e., $f=g$ a.e. in $\Omega$ and $f=g$ in $L^2(\Omega)$, are equivalent by definition, since $L^2(\Omega)$ is constructed as a quotient space by the subspace of functions with $f=0$ a.e.